# Как сделать что бы при валидации поля модели выводило только ошибку без поля

Tags: django

Мой пример: models.py

```py
def validate_availability(value):
    if value < 1:
        raise ValidationError(('Укажите количество'), params={'value': value}, )
```

если значение меньше 1, тогда выводит:

```
*availability  
*Укажите количество
```

а хотелось бы видеть только:

```
*Укажите количество
```

Comment: можете переопределить `clean` модели, и валидировать поле там. ошибки из `clean`, если не указано поле, выводятся для всего объекта а не для поля

Comment: но я бы посмотрел в исходниках, как в форме появляются ошибки (или где вы их получаете), и исходя из этого, написал бы функцию, которая преобразовывала формат вывода